# Need to remove ObjectID() from _id using Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am retrieving records from Mongo using Meteor. I use the {{_id}} placeholder in my meteor template to use the _id field of the record, but it adds this into my template....

```
ObjectID("54f27a1adfe0c11c824e04e9")
```

... and I would like just to have...

```
54f27a1adfe0c11c824e04e9
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just add a global helper:

```js
Template.registerHelper('formatId', function(data) {
  return (data && data._str) || data;
});
```

You can also do it like this with ES6 syntax :

```js
Template.registerHelper('formatId', (id) => (id && id._str) || id);
```

And use it in any template like this:

```
{{formatId _id}}
```

This will work for both mongo-style ObjectIds and meteor-style random strings.

Answer (score 1):

Since your documents are using the MongoDB ID format rather than the default Meteor ID format (simply a randomly generated string), you will need to use the MongoDB `ObjectId.toString()` function described [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.toString/). But unfortunately, this simply results in your ObjectID being printed out as a string like `ObjectID("54f27a1adfe0c11c824e04e9")`.

I would recommend creating a document ID template helper that cleans your document IDs before including them in the template. Since this issue is most likely related to all of your documents in all of your collections, I would further suggest creating a global template helper. This can be done like so:

```
Template.registerHelper('cleanDocumentID', function(objectID) {
    var objectIdString = objectID.toString();
    var cleanedString = objectIDString.slice(objectIDString.indexOf('"') + 1, -2);

    return cleanedString;
});
```

This template helper slices out just the actual object ID string from the string provided by the `ObjectId.toString()` function. You can use this template helper in your templates like so:

```
{{cleanDocumentID _id}}
```

I know that this is a lot messier than simply using the document ID in the template like `{{_id}}`, but it is necessary due to the fact that your documents have the MongoDB ObjectID-type document ID rather than the simple randomly generated string as used by Meteor by default.

If you would like to learn more about how to set your MongoDB collections to use randomly generated strings for document IDs and avoid this mess, check out [this](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection).

Comment: Is it possible to switch between the 'idGeneration' method once records have started to be generate in my application? Also, which is the best method - STRING or MONGO?

Comment: It doesn't seem possible to switch the ID generation scheme once a collection is created. This is most likely desired behavior for Meteor because you would always want to be consistent with how you generate IDs for documents in a given collection. As far as which method is best, I think that they are probably both about even in terms of quality. The Meteor package random string generated might be better because it uses a larger character set for creating the strings, whereas the MongoDB IDs are only hexadecimal strings.

Answer (score 1):

In Blaze templates, just add this `{{_id.valueOf}}`, and you will have a string value of the actual Object Id.

Answer (score 0):

mongo is capable of storing many types including uuids and custom ones. the field is usually a self-describing object, comprised of the type and the id.

your record is using the default mongo format evidenced by the "ObjectId" prefix.

try `ObjectId("507f191e810c19729de860ea").str`